# PHP on IIS7 - Receiving "Object Moved" html page instead of actually redirecting

Tags: php, iis, iis-7.5

I'm learning PHP on my computer with IIS7.5 as the web server and am having a problem completing a 301 redirect correctly.

The tutorials and forums all say to use the following:

```
Header('Location: ' . $url, true, 301);
```

OR

```
Header('Location: ' . $url);
```

In both cases, instead of actually redirecting, the browser (Chrome and Firefox) display this:

```
Object Moved

This document may be found here
```

Using the FireFox web developer toolbar, I retrieved the page headers, which were:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5, ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 21 Mar 2011 18:47:35 GMT
Content-Length: 123

301 Moved Permanently
```

Why is the page not redirecting? Displaying that page is kind of redundant and annoying for users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. The Location header must be an absolute path to auto-redirect. If it's a relative path it doesn't redirect.

Comment: It's actually your browser rather than PHP or your server config - the requirement for a full URL is part of HTTP/1.1, but some clients will follow a URI.

Comment: I observed the same result in FireFox 3.6 and Chrome 10. IE9 didn't do anything at all, it just displayed a page error.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue but the path was already absolute. I solved it by specifically sending a 301 header before the location. PHP is supposed to detect redirects and do this automatically but wasn't doing.

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("location:http://www.mysite.com/mypage.php");
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem using PHP on IIS7 using absolute URL. Bugged me for a little while. Ensure that you put 
    exit();
after your 
    header('Location: https://domain.tld/resource'); 
the header doesn't stop execution, and the function will otherwise return somewhere giving maybe unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a easy hack to fix this. Use an Outbound Redirect rule to set the Content Length header in redirect responses to 0. Browsers will truncate the sent response body automatically based on the Content Length header.

Here is my redirect rule:

```
<rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Remove Content from Redirect Requests" preCondition="Is30xStatus" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_CONTENT_LENGTH" pattern="*" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="0" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
            <preCondition name="Is30xStatus">
                <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="^30[1-8]$" />
            </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

I would recommend using that as a reference to create a new outbound rewrite rule using the IIS Manager as editing web.config files directly can have unexpected results.

Update:
Apparently there is a PHP directive that changes the format of the headers to help with this as well:

cgi.rfc2616_headers = 1

I have tested this on my server, and this seems to help the issue as well.

Comment: Okay, I can see this removes the entire response. I'm getting this issue on a 201 Created status from my api, so I need my api to return the new object and its id. Are there any good "hacks" to just remove that silly html header that iis spits out?

Comment: Have you tried setting a conditional outbound rule? I think your comment probably warrants a whole new question with all of the extra details and information necessary to answer it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. Posted here: https://forums.iis.net/p/1234223/2126740.aspx?Re+Python+REST+API+Status+201+Create+IIS+Adds+HTML