# Object Moved page on PHP login script

Tags: php, redirect

I've put together a login script, and by put together I mean I copy and pasted bits and pieces of code from forums and got it working from trial and error.

So far the script is working fine, when logging in there is no issue at all, the only problem comes from when you try to login without filling in any of the fields, it gives me some strange error and redirects me to a blank page with

> Object Moved
>
> This document may be found here

It's not a huge issue as I don't see why people would try and login with blank fields anyway, but it's something I'd like to know how to solve for future reference.

Below is the login portion of my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$data=array("user1"=>array("url"=>"page1.php","password"=>"12345"),
            "user2"=>array("url"=>"page2.php","password"=>"12345"),
        "user3"=>array("url"=>"page3.php","password"=>"12345")
        );

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    $user = strtolower($_POST['username']);
    $pass = strtolower($_POST['password']);

    if($data[$user]['password'] == $pass) {     
       $_SESSION['username'] = $user . " " . $pass;
       header('Location: ' . $data[$user]['url']);
    } else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = function() { document.getElementById("loginError").innerHTML = "' . "Invalid login details. Please try again." . '"; }</script>';
        logIn();
    }
} else {
    logIn();
}
?>
```

Comment: Change `isset` to `!empty` and everything will be fixed. I'm sure someone else will come around and explain why.

Comment: Thanks Dan, that almost solves my issue. If both fields are left blank it will do nothing (as it should), but if the username is filled and pass left blank it still has the same issue.

I think I understand what you've suggested. I'm assuming isset is a check to see if they're defined whereas !empty would check for Not Empty. Or I could be completely wrong haha.

Comment: That means you didn't change both `isset` to `!empty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure or change that the `header('Location: ' . $data[$user]['url']); is an absolute path when redirecting and not a relative path. See the related post as proof for my answer [PHP on IIS7 - Receiving "Object Moved" html page instead of actually redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382219/php-on-iis7-receiving-object-moved-html-page-instead-of-actually-redirecting).

To fix that blank password issue change the check to the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && 
    isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password']) ) { 
    //Do code here
}
else
{
   logIn(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I actually stumbled across that exact thread but I'm quite new to PHP so most of the information flew right over me.

Your solution worked perfectly though!

Comment: empty() already performs isset()... this is what I wrote in my comment 37 minutes ago, except with superfluous code added. Do not do it like this. http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

When you compare strings you want to use `===` or `!==`:

```
...
$user = strtolower(trim($_POST['username']));
$pass = strtolower(trim($_POST['password']));

if($user !== '' && $pass !== '') {
  //continue with login logic
  if($data[$user]['password'] === $pass) { 
  ...
}
else{
//print error
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I decided to go with JLC007's answer though as it works fine also and is easier for me to understand.

Comment: @DanGrossman the `trim` takes care of null value - it will return the empty string.

Answer (score -1):

i think there is no logIn() function defined....please check. if yet, please post code for your html as well.

Comment: There is a login function, I just didn't post it as I found it irrelevant. Issue has been solved though thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

You should check that the username exists in your array before trying to read the password and URL for that nonexistant array index.

```
session_start();

$data=array("user1"=>array("url"=>"page1.php","password"=>"12345"),
            "user2"=>array("url"=>"page2.php","password"=>"12345"),
            "user3"=>array("url"=>"page3.php","password"=>"12345")
            );

if (!empty($_POST['username'] && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

    $user = strtolower($_POST['username']);
    $pass = strtolower($_POST['password']);

    if (isset($data[$user]) && $data[user]['password'] == $pass) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user . ' ' . $pass;
        header("Location: " . $daa[$user]['url']);
    } else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = function() { document.getElementById("loginError").innerHTML = "' . "Invalid login details. Please try again." . '"; }</script>';
        logIn();
    }

} else {
    logIn();
}
```